# Як перекласти "это ещё цветочки/всего лишь цветочки по сравнению"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Декілька прикладів:

> Это просто цветочки по сравнению с тем, что ждёт вас за этими стенами.
>
> Но их страдания - всего лишь цветочки, по сравнению с судьбой, которую я уготовила тебе.

Дослівний переклад цих прикладів:

> Це просто квіточки у порівнянні з тим, що чекає на вас за цими стінами.
>
> Але їхні страждання - лише квіточки у порівнянні з долею, що її я тобі підготувала.

Єдиний переклад, який приходить в голову - `це лише/лишень квіточки`, проте я ніколи такого виразу в українській не вживав і не бачив в письмовому вигляді(щоденний суржик українців не береться до уваги), тому не знаю чи він існує. Доказу протилежного я не знайшов.

Шукав в Інтернеті - взагалі нічого не знайшов. Знайшов лише щось в [російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua), проте перекладену версію я також ніколи ніде не зустрічав, виглядає як дослівний переклад:

> **Это только цветочки, а ягодки впереди.**
> *Се тільки цвіт (іноді цвіть), а ягідок пождіть. Пр. Це тільки цвіт, а  ягідки будуть. Пр.*

Я впевнений, що має існувати аналогічний цьому вираз українською або якась усталена конструкція - приказка/прислів'я або фразеологізм. Переклад в російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів в мене викликає сумніви.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96091/discussion-on-question-by-improbable-------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вираз *"это ещё цветочки"* [вживають](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91_%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9), коли говорять:

> о чём-либо негативном, что обещает проявиться в гораздо большей мере, чем сейчас

Тобто:

> про щось негативне, що, як видається, стане ще гіршим, ніж зараз

Думаю, цьому російському виразу відповідає (принаймні, частково) вираз *"**це ще півбіди**"*.

[Приклади](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac6&reload=&iquery=%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B8&queryselector=iqueryrow&lemma=&phrase=&word=&char=&cql=&default_attr=word&fc_lemword_window_type=both&fc_lemword_wsize=5&fc_lemword=&fc_lemword_type=all&usesubcorp=&fsca_doc.author=&fsca_doc.translator=&fsca_doc.authTrans=&fsca_doc.born=&fsca_doc.title=&fsca_doc.date=&fsca_doc.mediaName=&fsca_doc.locCode=&fsca_doc.region=&fsca_doc.publisher=&fsca_doc.publication=&fsca_doc.uri=):

> *Боліла в Лесі голова, весь час хотілося спати. Майже нічого не їла. Та й **це ще було півбіди** в порівнянні з тим, що сталось кількома днями пізніше. А сталося справді жахливе.* (Микола Олійник - "Дочка Прометея", 1966)
>
> *Нічого, **то ще півбіди**, — потішив його хтось. — Біда попереду.* (Іван Багряний - "Сад Гетсиманський", 1950)

Хоча *"це ще півбіди"* не завжди означає, що може трапитись щось ще гірше (порівняно з тим, що є зараз). Іноді ним послуговуються, коли порівнюють дві ситуації, які не йдуть одна за одною:

> *Якби йшлося справді про блохи, то **це ще півбіди**, а то йдеться сьогодні про життя або смерть людства.* (Микола Руденко - "Слідами космічної катастрофи", 1962)
>
> *Якщо голова чи його заступник щось візьме собі — **це ще півбіди**, а коли кожний потягне собі, то що тоді буде?* (Михайло Стельмах - "Правда і кривда", 1961)

[Інші відповідники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%86%D0%B5+%D1%89%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) російського виразу:

> це ще нічого;
>
> це ще дарма;
>
> це ще дурниця;
>
> це ще півбіди лиха.